# delete all log streams of a log group using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

In order to delete a log stream from a log group using the CLI command , individual log stream names are required .
Is there a way to delete all log streams belonging to a log group using a single command?

Answer (score 43):

You can achieve this through using `--query` to target the results of `describe-log-streams`. This allows you to loop through and delete the results.

`aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP_NAME --query 'logStreams[*].logStreamName' --output table | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ^$ | while read x; do aws logs delete-log-stream --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP_NAME --log-stream-name $x; done`

You can use `--query` to target all or specific groups or streams.

**Delete streams from a specific month**

`` aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP --query 'logStreams[?starts_with(logStreamName,`2017/07`)].logStreamName' --output table | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ^$ | while read x; do aws logs delete-log-stream --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP --log-stream-name $x; done ``

**Delete All log groups - Warning, it deletes EVERYTHING!**

`aws logs describe-log-groups --query 'logGroups[*].logGroupName' --output table | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ^$ | while read x; do aws logs delete-log-group --log-group-name $x; done`

**Clearing specific log groups**

`` aws logs describe-log-groups --query 'logGroups[?starts_with(logGroupName,`$LOG_GROUP_NAME`)].logGroupName' --output table | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ^$ | while read x; do aws logs delete-log-group --log-group-name $x; done ``

[Credit](https://gist.github.com/pahud/1e875cb1252a622173cc2236be5c2963)

Comment: This works but deletes all of the log _groups_. The OP is asking how to delete the log _streams_ within a group.

Comment: @brianz good point, I have updated the answer to correctly answer the question asked

Comment: Instead of outputting the list of streams in a visual table format and then using awk and grep to extract the contents of the table, you can just output in text format like this `aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP_NAME --query 'logStreams[*].[logStreamName]' --output text | while read x; do aws logs delete-log-stream --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP_NAME --log-stream-name $x; done`

Answer (score 13):

Implemented script with command from @Stephen's answer. The script shows summary before deletion and tracks progress of deletion.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOG_GROUP_NAME=${1:?log group name is not set}

echo Getting stream names...
LOG_STREAMS=$(
    aws logs describe-log-streams \
        --log-group-name ${LOG_GROUP_NAME} \
        --query 'logStreams[*].logStreamName' \
        --output table |
        awk '{print $2}' |
        grep -v ^$ |
        grep -v DescribeLogStreams
)

echo These streams will be deleted:
printf "${LOG_STREAMS}\n"
echo Total $(wc -l <<<"${LOG_STREAMS}") streams
echo

while true; do
    read -p "Prceed? " yn
    case $yn in
    [Yy]*) break ;;
    [Nn]*) exit ;;
    *) echo "Please answer yes or no." ;;
    esac
done

for name in ${LOG_STREAMS}; do
    printf "Delete stream ${name}... "
    aws logs delete-log-stream --log-group-name ${LOG_GROUP_NAME} --log-stream-name ${name} && echo OK || echo Fail
done
```

[Github link](https://github.com/Zebradil/aws-scripts/blob/master/delete-log-streams-from-group.sh)

Comment: Thanks for this! I use it nearly every day.

Comment: @Kilhoffer I'm a bit late for the party, but wouldn't it be easier to set a shorter retention for your loggroups so old logentries will be deleted automatically?

Answer (score 11):

To delete all log streams associated with a specific log group, run the following command, replacing NAME_OF_LOG_GROUP with your group:

```
aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name NAME_OF_LOG_GROUP --output text | awk '{print $7}' | while read x; 
do aws logs delete-log-stream --log-group-name NAME_OF_LOG_GROUP --log-stream-name $x
done
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is Script to delete all logs in a log group using python. Just change the `logGroupName` to match your logGroup.

```python
import boto3

client = boto3.client('logs')

response = client.describe_log_streams(
    logGroupName='/aws/batch/job'
)


def delete_stream(stream):
    delete_response = client.delete_log_stream(
        logGroupName='/aws/batch/job',
        logStreamName=stream['logStreamName']
    )

    print(delete_response)


results = map(lambda x: delete_stream(x), response['logStreams'])
```

Comment: there is however a very small issue with the above script. It would still not delete `all` the streams in the specified log group. That's because `describe_log_streams` has a limitation of pulling up the 1st 50 records *at max* alone. 
So we could add another loop over this and get all the streams deleted IMHO.

Comment: Or still better, *pagination* could be used like this:

```paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_log_streams')```
```pg_response = paginator.paginate(logGroupName='/aws/batch/job', PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': 100000})```
```response = pg_response.build_full_result()```
```results = map(lambda x: delete_stream(x), response['logStreams'])```

Answer (score 4):

Based on @german-lashevich's answer

If you have thousands of log streams, you will needed to parallelize.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOG_GROUP_NAME=${1:?log group name is not set}

echo Getting stream names...
LOG_STREAMS=$(
    aws logs describe-log-streams \
        --log-group-name ${LOG_GROUP_NAME} \
        --query 'logStreams[*].logStreamName' \
        --output table |
        awk '{print $2}' |
        grep -v ^$ |
        grep -v DescribeLogStreams
)

echo These streams will be deleted:
printf "${LOG_STREAMS}\n"
echo Total $(wc -l <<<"${LOG_STREAMS}") streams
echo

while true; do
    read -p "Prceed? " yn
    case $yn in
    [Yy]*) break ;;
    [Nn]*) exit ;;
    *) echo "Please answer yes or no." ;;
    esac
done

step() {
    local name=$1
    printf "Delete stream ${name}... "
    aws logs delete-log-stream --log-group-name ${LOG_GROUP_NAME} --log-stream-name ${name} && echo OK || echo Fail
}

N=20
for name in ${LOG_STREAMS}; do ((i=i%N)); ((i++==0)) && wait ; step "$name" & done
```

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users this powershell script could be usefull, to remove all the log streams in a log group:

```
#Set your log group name
$log_group_name = "/production/log-group-name"

aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name $log_group_name --query logStreams --output json | ConvertFrom-json | ForEach-Object {$_.logStreamName} | ForEach-Object {
    aws logs delete-log-stream --log-group-name $log_group_name --log-stream-name $_
    Write-Host ($_ + " -> deleted") -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Just save it as *your_script_name.ps1* and execute it in powershell.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done using a single aws Cli command. Hence we achieved this using a script where we first retrieved all the log streams of a log group and then deleted them in a loop.

Comment: I will appreciate if you could provide the script.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative version using Powershell CLI on Windows, launch powershell command line and use:

```
$LOG_GROUP_NAME="cloud-watch-group-name";
$LOG_STREAM_NAMEP="cloud-watch-log-stream-name";

Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region us-your-regions;
Set-AWSCredential -AccessKey ACCESSKEYEXAMPLE -SecretKey sEcReTKey/EXamPLE/xxxddddEXAMPLEKEY -StoreAs MyProfileName

Get-CWLLogStream -loggroupname $LOG_GROUP_NAME -logstreamnameprefix $LOG_GROUP_NAMEP | Remove-CWLLogStream -LogGroupName $LOG_GROUP_NAME;
```

You may use **-Force** parameter on the **Remove-CWLogStream** Cmdlet in case you don´t want to confirm one by one.

References
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html

Answer (score 1):

The others have already described how you can paginate through all the log streams and delete them one by one.

I would like to offer two alternative ways that have (more or less) the same effect, but don't require you to loop through all the log streams.

---

Deleting the log *group*, then re-creating it has the desired effect: All the log streams of the log group will be deleted.

- [delete-log-group](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/delete-log-group.html)

followed by:

- [create-log-group](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/create-log-group.html)

**CAVEAT:** Deleting a log group can have unintended consequences. For example, subscriptions and the retention policy will be deleted as well, and those have to be restored too when the log group is re-created.

---

Another workaround is to set a 1 day retention period.

- [put-retention-policy](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/put-retention-policy.html)

It won't have an immediate effect, you will have to wait ca. a day, but after that all the old data will be deleted. The name of the old streams and their meta data (last event time, creation time, etc.) will remain though, but you won't be charged for that (as far as I can tell based on my own bill).

So it is not exactly what you asked for. However, probably the most important reason why one would want to delete all the log streams is to delete the logged data (to reduce costs, or for compliance reasons), and this approach achieves that.

**WARNING:** Don't forget to change the retention policy after the old data is gone, or you will continually delete data after 1 day, and chances are, it is not what you want in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in zshell /zsh and you only need simple one liner command then just update the values :

```
* Pattern
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

- Pattern can any text , you can also add ^ for begging of the line or $ for end of the line.

run the below command !

```
Pattern="YOUR_PATTERN" && setupKeys="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOUR_KEY AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YOUR_KEY AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=YOUR_REGION" && 
eval "${setupKeys} aws logs describe-log-groups --query 'logGroups[*].logGroupName' --output table | sed 's/|//g'| sed 's/\s//g'| grep -i ${Pattern} "| while read x; do  echo "deleting $x" && $setupKeys aws logs delete-log-group --log-group-name $x; done
```

Answer (score 0):

--log-group-name is not optional in aws cli, you can try using an * for --log-group-name value (in test environment)

aws logs delete-log-group --log-group-name my-logs

Reference URL: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/delete-log-group.html

Comment: I would like to delete all log streams under a log-group using the CLI. Not the log group

Comment: This is an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a prefix, you could use the following command.

```
aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name <log_group_name> --log-stream-name-prefix"<give_a_log_group_prefix>" --query 'logStreams[*].logStreamName' --output table | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ^$ | while read x; do aws logs delete-log-stream --log-group-name <log_group_name> --log- stream-name $x;done;
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick dirty py script with pagination to delete all steams in a group.

Set `log_group_name` from terminal input or un comment to set in code.

```
import boto3

# take input
print('log group name:')
log_group_name = input()

# or set in code
# log_group_name = '' # set your log name

client = boto3.client('logs')


def run(next_token: str = None):
    print(f'batch w/token: {next_token}')
    params = {
        'logGroupName': log_group_name
    }
    if next_token:
        params['nextToken'] = next_token
    response_streams = client.describe_log_streams(**params)
    streams = response_streams['logStreams']
    for stream in streams:
        log_stream_name = stream['logStreamName']
        response_delete = client.delete_log_stream(
            logGroupName=log_group_name,
            logStreamName=log_stream_name
        )
        success = response_delete.get('ResponseMetadata', {}).get('HTTPStatusCode') == 200
        print(f'delete {log_stream_name} - {"success" if success else "failed..."}')
    return response_streams.get('nextToken')


# process
next_token = run()
while next_token:
    next_token = run(next_token)
```